# Mouse pointer invisible with color inversion using xcalib

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, cursor, wolfram-mathematica, mouse

I use xcalib on Ubuntu to invert my colors.
All colors invert, except my mouse pointer.

This results in an invisible mouse pointer in Mathematica and Eclipse. (black background and black mouse cursor) These programs override the default mouse cursor.

Please let me know how to invert my mouse cursor when my screen inverts. (or let my system prevent the overriding of the default cursor)